# android studio not working, internal error

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio upgraded itself automatically. However,whenever I tried opening it, this error occurred

```
    Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
    at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried re-installing it but the same thing happens. Whats the issue and how can i resolve it(and if possible, send links where I can read on similar issues)

Comment: I was not opening any project at all, like android studio is not starting at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there is some issue with the support of some plugins in the new android studio version.
This are the steps I used to solve my issue and I hope it works for you too:

1. go to home/.local folder/share
2. find Google folder and delete it
3. Open Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for your problem. Jetbrains has integrated into one of your projects and added itself to android studio. The issue lies in the fact jetbrains is not installed on your local machine so to fix your issue please install the jetbrains toolbox linked here:
-> https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/  .... This should fix your issue as it fixed mine and set you on your way. Happy coding :)